# Why do snap packages disappear when using the Fish shell?

Tags: snap, wayland, fish

If I take a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10, install a package via snap, and change my shell to fish, after logging in again the package is missing from gnome-shell's menu and from my favorites list.

Weirdly, this also only happens when using Wayland.

What could cause this issue? I can confirm my shell works normally and the path is normal. I can also confirm these applications run fine via snap run or their command line versions, but it's as if the *.desktop files are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create ~/.config/fish/config.fish if it doesn't exist, and add the following two lines

```
set PATH /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin $PATH
set XDG_DATA_DIRS /var/lib/snapd/desktop/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

This will put snap applications on your path and make your shortcut icons available.

Answer (score 5):

#### The problem: The issue is linked to your login shell.

The variable `XDG_DATA_DIRS` is set when `/etc/profile.d` is sourced (`/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh`)

But if you use fish-shell, as is your case, or zsh, you are not sourcing `/etc/profile.d/` and therefore `XDG_DATA_DIRS` is never set and the `.desktop` files in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop` won't be found. That's not a bug but it's due to fish not being POSIX 1003.1 compatible. That meaning that these shells doesn't understand the bash syntax.

#### The workaround:

I can think of at least two workarounds.

1. The simple one is to reverse the default shell to bash with

   ```
   chsh -s /bin/bash
   ```

   And then add the line

   ```
   fish
   ```

   At the end of the `~/.bashrc`. By doing this your login shell would be bash and your `/etc/profile.d` would be sourced, but you would be using fish every time you open your terminal. And writing 'exit' on your terminal would jump back to bash.
2. A trickiest one is to keep fish as your login shell but force the `/etc/profile.d` to be sourced. To do this you need to follow these steps:

   1. from you fish shell install fisher and bass (make Bash utilities usable in Fish shell).

      ```
      curl -Lo ~/.config/fish/functions/fisher.fish --create-dirs https://git.io/fisher 

      # instruct fisher to download the bass package   
      fisher add edc/bass
      ```
   2. edit your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (create It if it doesn't exist) and source every file under `/etc/profile.d` using bass.

      ```
      nano ~/.config/fish/config.fish
      ```

      (In another terminal `ls` the `/etc/profile.d directory` to get the  list of files. Copy them)

      Paste the list in your nano terminal like this:

      ```
      bass source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh 

      bass source /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh 

      bass source /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh 

      bass source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh 

      bass source /etc/profile.d/input-method-config.sh 

      bass source /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
      ```

      Save, close, close session or restart and 'ta-da'.

   With this option you keep fish as your login shell but you have to check the `/etc/profile.d` directory every now and then to make sure there isn't a new file your not sourcing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what is suggested in [Esteban Vergara's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990071/why-do-snap-packages-disappear-when-using-the-fish-shell/1004536#1004536), I added these lines to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```
for file in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
        bass source $file
end
```

This will prevent the issue of having to check your `profile.d` folder regularly as he suggested, as it will recursively load all sh files in that folder on session start.

Comment: Just a small addition: redirecting the error output to `/dev/null` will avoid an ugly "permission  denied" to some root read-only files in `profile.d`. The complete line would be `bass source $file 2> /dev/null`. To make this answer more complete, I would just mention that `bass` can be installed with `omf`, using `omf install bass`